# How to avoid updating Stale widgets in android

Tags: android, size, widget

In many tutorials, the updating of a widget is suggested to be as follows;

```
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds) {
      final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
       int widgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

Log.d(TAG, " ## onUpdate ## , appWidgetIds.length = "+ String.valueOf(appWidgetIds.length) + " appWidgetId = " + widgetId );

       context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdateService.class));
      }
}
```

However, though there is only one widget on my homescreen, the size of appWidgetIds returns 52 and each one of them tries to process an update. This, of course, causes an overload on the called service, eventually crashing the application.

In his [post](http://kmansoft.wordpress.com/2010/06/22/per-widget-options-stale-widgets/#comment-315), Kostya Vasilyev offers a workaround for this bug.

This should be quite a common issue but I couldnT find any alternatives to this solution. How could we identify the stale widgets and avoid trying to update them?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT :** I ve just figured one good way to avoid stale widgets is to stop the running service (if there is any), upon the completion of the code in it :) This seems to have saved my day, of course it s not the answer though.

Comment: sorry for posting here. You asked if i still needed help on my problem with widgets running db queries... do you know a solution by any chance? I've been struggling with this for a week now. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @Andre :) yeah I solved it actually. I ll post the answer whenever I can. Also see the **Edit** ? Try stopping ur service when u donT need it, or donT start it all over again (for widget `onupdate()` for example) if you donT want to stop it. Meanwhile i d suggest you mark this for deletion, and post it as a comment or smth.